# Which version for a netbook (Eee PC 1001 HA)?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, eeepc

I have been using easy peasy 1.6 on my old EeePC 1001 HA. Things are working well. The only thing, the updating software seems not to be working. 
That is why I am looking for another ubuntu version that is up to date, easy to use and fast.

What version do you recommend ?

Here are the specs : 
CPU & Chipset
Intel® Atom™ N270
Memory
DDR2 SO-DIMM 1GB
Wireless Data Network
WLAN 802.11b/g/n @2.4GHz

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just helped my brother get an old Eee PC 1015PE updating again even though it is running an obsolete version of Ubuntu. The trick is to edit /etc/apt/sources.list and change every reference to *.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com. You won't get security updates or the latest software, but it can postpone having to consider a complete OS upgrade.